# Facebook Multiquery Error

Tags: facebook

I am having an issue with facebook multiquery syntax

When I use single query like .simply copy and paste it in your browser and you will get results

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=243995185663734 AND metric='application_active_users' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-11-30') AND period=period('month')&access_token=243995185663734%7C3fAfdJJqdrgA99XWdE5K6zzeNR8
```

It gives me exact true results.  But now I want to use multiquery because i have to fetch data for multiple metrics but it gives me error.

I use this query

```
 https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery? queries  ="{"query1": "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=208344135910932 AND metric='application_active_users' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-11-30') AND period=period('month')","query2": "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=208344135910932 AND metric='application_active_users' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-11-30') AND period=period('month')"}"&access_token=243995185663734|3fAfdJJqdrgA99XWdE5K6zzeNR8
```

Please tell me if I am using some wrong syntax for multiquery.  This is the error response which I am getting in xml.

```
 <error_response xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">
    <error_code>100</error_code>
    <error_msg>The parameter queries is required</error_msg>
    <request_args list="true"><arg>
    <key>method</key>
    <value>fql.multiquery</value>
    </arg><arg>
    <key>queries__</key>
    <value>"{"query1": "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=208344135910932 AND metric='application_active_users' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-11-30') AND period=period('month')","query2": "SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=208344135910932 AND metric='application_active_users' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-11-30') AND period=period('month')"}"
    </value>
    </arg><arg>
    <key>access_token</key>
    <value>243995185663734|3fAfdJJqdrgA99XWdE5K6zzeNR8</value></arg></request_args></error_response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some spaces and extra quotations around your JSON, try

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery?queries={%22query1%22:%20%22SELECT%20metric,%20value%20FROM%20insights%20WHERE%20object_id=208344135910932%20AND%20metric='application_active_users'%20AND%20end_time=end_time_date('2011-11-30')%20AND%20period=period('month')%22,%22query2%22:%20%22SELECT%20metric,%20value%20FROM%20insights%20WHERE%20object_id=208344135910932%20AND%20metric='application_active_users'%20AND%20end_time=end_time_date('2011-11-30')%20AND%20period=period('month')%22}&access_token=243995185663734|3fAfdJJqdrgA99XWdE5K6zzeNR8
```

With this call, I get back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fql_multiquery_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd" list="true">
  <fql_result>
    <name>query1</name>
    <fql_result_set list="true">
      <insights>
        <metric>application_active_users</metric>
        <value>0</value>
      </insights>
    </fql_result_set>
  </fql_result>
  <fql_result>
    <name>query2</name>
    <fql_result_set list="true">
      <insights>
        <metric>application_active_users</metric>
        <value>0</value>
      </insights>
    </fql_result_set>
  </fql_result>
</fql_multiquery_response>
```